# Can MongoDB be forced to use a partial index for a field when the query does not fit the partial index filter expression?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

Is it possible to have a query return 0 results (when if no index existed **it is possible** there would be at least 1 result) because the partial index for the field being queried does not include qualifying documents?

The scenario that has lead to this question is having a partial index that enforces uniqueness on a field with an `exists` filter such that it will ignore documents where that field is `null`.

It would be ideal if a way existed so that any queries on that collection for `null` values of that field would still use that partial index and return no results - avoiding the full collection scan that actually does happen in that case and leads to a very slow query.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I see is to add the `yourField: { $exists: true }` condition all queries, which do not already filter for that field. (the other fields need ofc also meet the index requirements.)